# persistent left panel in all windows in c#?

Tags: c#

Hi I would like to have a persistent or constant left panel among all Forms of a c#  Desktop applicaton . I however would not like to use the inheritance way of doing it . Could some one point out a suggestion or the right search terms to find  examples like these in google ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use inheritance here?  Seems like a reasonable way to approach it.

Comment: What technology? Winforms? WPF?

Comment: dup ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218656/winform-templating-system-like-asp-net-masterpage-or-ms-access-subform

Comment: @  david hall .. Is it simpler in WPF form s??

Answer (score 0):

I believe inheritance is the only way.  Is there any particular reason you cannot do this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to build a modular client application. Consider looking at Prism for this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648611.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own user control with a left panel and use that in all your Forms. But I do agree that inheritance is a cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use inheritance, but if all the forms are being shown by the same form, simply add your Panel before they're shown:

```
Panel p = new Panel();
// Set up the panel here
TheForm f = new TheForm();
// Set up the form here
f.Controls.Add(p);
f.Show();
```